# AngularJS: get url path without routeParams

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

Take this route for exmaple

```
when('/coordinator/editApplications/:appId', {
        templateUrl: 'assets/app/templates/coordinator/editApplications.tpl.html',
        module: "/coordinator",
    })
```

Without using regular expressions, is there a property/method available in Angular that will allow me to get the `path` value with the parameters stripped off?

The value I would want for this example would be `/coordinator/editApplications`

This needs to be be universal because there could be multiple params or differently named params. I can't find anyway on the `$route` or `$location` to get this value as they all seem to contain the params.

Again, I know i can use regExp to do this but I want to avoid that.  I also don't want to just add another property to the route w/ the non-param url value.

Comment: should be fairly easy to use properties in params and remove each of the values from url.

Comment: window.location ? But, as you mentioned with the parameters stripped off, you'll still have to use regExp to get rid of the numbers. Or if you know it's exactly that path, you could simply use split(string, '/') and join without the last variable.